# Generating random integer in variables

Tags: javascript, random

I am in need to generate an integer with the value of maximum 3 and it cannot be 0.

I am a newbie on Javascript so i tried to do this.

```
var x = 4;
var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*x);
var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*x);
var randomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*x);

while (randomNumber1 === randomNumber2, randomNumber1 === 0, randomNumber2 === 0){
var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*x);
} 

while (randomNumber2 === randomNumber3, randomNumber2 === 0, randomNumber3 === 0){
var randomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*x);
} 

while (randomNumber3 === randomNumber1, randomNumber3 === 0, randomNumber1 === 0){
var randomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*x);
} 
console.log(randomNumber1);
console.log(randomNumber2);
console.log(randomNumber3);
```

it still shows 0´s and equal numbers
im sure i am not right but i think im on the right way.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: maybe you mean `||` instead of `,`?

Comment: Using `||` won't fix it. If `randomNumber1` is `0`, generating a new `randomNumber2` won't change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good way to obfuscate your code. You can get it a lot cleaner and a lot more readable:

```
Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);// Scratch this, this can actually return 0.

Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
```

Answer (score -2):

Math.random() gives a random number between 0 and 1. 2*Math.random() gives a random number between 0 and 2, and rounding that Math.round(2*Math.random()) gives values of 0, 1, and 2. Adding one gives 1, 2, and 3, which is what you are looking for

```
var randomNumber = 1 + Math.round(2*Math.random());
```

Comment: Using `round()` will bias the numbers towards `2`.